# Why does the Swipe Gesture Recognizer only work once?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I set up a `Swipe Gesture Recognizer` and I connected it to the code, so that an `UIImageView` rotates when the user swipes to the left.

```
@IBAction func swipeToLeft(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.image.transform, -3.14159265358979 )
    })
}
```

I made sure the `viewDidLoad` method looked like this:

```
image.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

However, the `UIImageView` only gets transformed **only once**.

You can download the demo of the project from this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50m7n2m2c5bikj3/DemoSwipe.zip?dl=0). Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the problem is that the moment you rotated your image, the gesture recognizer, associated with it, also got rotated. You can make sure yourself:

Make a swipe right-to-left. The image will rotate. Then make a swipe left-to-right. It will rotate again.

If you want to always handle a swipe right-to-left, you can do it in a couple of ways:

1. If your view is always rotated by 180 degrees, the easiest way is to change the gesture recognizer orientation (@LyndseyScott was faster than me to right the code for this one, you can check her answer :) ).
2. Another option (especially, if there might be a situation, when you rotate your view by some arbitrary angle), is to create a UIView on top of the view you want to rotate (but not as its subview!), and to add the gesture recognizer to it instead.

Comment: Yes, I was about to post the same answer. I downloaded the OP's code and this is in fact what's happening.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. I do not get your last sentence. What do you mean exactly by that? Do you mean I should use a `swipeToRight` `UIGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: @CeceXX, no, I mean, make a swipe in the simulator (or wherever you test your project). First you swipe from right to left. It makes the image rotate. Then, if you try another swipe right to left, nothing happens. But if you tried a left to right swipe (the opposite direction, since you rotated your view by 180 degrees), it would rotate again.

Comment: Thank you. That doesn't fix my issue though. What if i do not want to swipe left to right and I would like to keep swiping right to left? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! The second point you made is really the key.  I will be using a `UIView` to handle these gestures nicely with another angles. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on FreeNickname's answer, since the gesture recognizer "rotates" along with the `UIImageView`, you can change your code to the following so that the swipe gesture swaps directions along with the image and you can continue swiping from right to left to trigger the animation:

```
@IBAction func swipeToLeft(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
            self.doubleDot.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.doubleDot.transform, -3.14159265358979 )
            }, completion: {
                (value: Bool) in
                if sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left {
                    sender.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
                } else {
                    sender.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
                }
        })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I do get an error when I try to run your code: `Cannot assign to direction in sender` in line `sender.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right` and `sender.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left`. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @CeceXX Update your swipeToLeft parameter from `AnyObject` to `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` as I've done in my updated code.

Comment: I was updating my answer to include ways to deal with this problem, but 1)  You were faster; 2) I'm not able to write code in Swift yet anyway :) So, +1 :) Teamwork :)

Comment: @LyndseyScott thanks for taking time answering my question and downloading the sample project. Appreciate your help!