# UISwipeGestureRecognizer working weird

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewanimation, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my `UiView` I have a `subView` called 'container' which should perform a rotation animation either if the user swipe up or down. 
Basically it's like a wheel where if the user swipe down the wheel swipe down of a certain degree while swiping up perform the opposite action.

Here's my viewDidLoad code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Swipe Gesture Recognizers Setup
    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeUp(_:)))
    swipeUp.direction = .up
    swipeUp.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeDown(_:)))
    swipeDown.direction = .down
    swipeDown.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
}
```

and these are the 2 functions for swipe up or down:

```
func swipeUp(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Swiped Up")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.borderContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
    }
}

func swipeDown(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Swiped Down")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.borderContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 45)
    }}
```

Everything works great, consolle is printing the swipe direction everytime the action is performed BUT (yeah there's a BUT!) it calls the related function only ONCE in each direction.
Meaning that if I swipe Down, then I can only Swipe up...

I want it to be able to keep swiping down or up anytime the user wants...

What am I doing wrong? 
I read about the UIGestureRecogniser rotating together with the view therefore it's not reachable anymore but I applied the solution to apply the Gesture Recogniser to the superView and not to the View I'm animating... [Why does the Swipe Gesture Recognizer only work once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386951/why-does-the-swipe-gesture-recognizer-only-work-once)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is you don't understand the transformation works, not the gesture recognition. You have to accumulate angles to achieve the desire rotation. For ex, for swiping down 2 times, you have to rotate 90 degrees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at your swipe down function. You set the same value every time you swipe down.

You need to **add** 45 degrees to the current angle if you want to change it every time. Otherwise it will continue to be in the same position as before.

Try to use `borderContainer.transform.rotated(by: 45)`.

Comment: Thanks! Although border.Container.transform.rotated didn't worked you gave me the correct hint on where to look at. I fixed with a simple case loop checking for angle and acting accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

**CGAffineTransform** choose only **shortest path** for rotation.Keep in mind that if you rotate something.Your swipe is ok but you need to modify rotation code a little bit to make it work.